# CakePHP : XXXController.index() is automatically called right after when XXXDetailController.confirm() completed

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

`XXXController.index()` searches and displays data as a list(table) with url including id of each data.Url format is `a href='/xXXDetail/index/id'`.

After clicking it,`XXXDetailController.index($id)` is called as `GET`and works without any problem. 
This displays index page with form, method is `POST`. `'/xxxx_detail/index/id'` is set as action.

After submitting it, it works without any problem. `XXXDetailController.index($id)` behaves as expected. End of `XXXDetailController.index($id)`, I call `$this->redirect(array('action' => confirm))`

After redirect, `XXXDetailController.confirm()` works. But cakePHP automatically calls `XXXController.index()` right after end of it in background regardless of displaying XXXDetail's confirm page.

I couldn't understand what is happening.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: what does the "XXX" mean? can you paste the index method of your controller?

Comment: It works without problem when I tested in Google Chrome! When I execute Google Chrome Canary, there is strange behavior above..